# Highcharts observable series is not updating chart

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to add/remove it's series whenever a new series in added into `chartSeries` property. `chartSeries` is an observable array. The problem is that it renders correctly only for the first time, any updates in the property is not effecting the chart.

```
ChartSettings = {
     chart: {
        type: 'line'
     },
     series: chartSeries
});
```

Any suggestion? JQuery solution is not recommended, leveraging an existing highcharts property would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931986/knockoutjs-dynamic-chart-with-high-charts#answer-9934952
A custom binding handler would be the correct Knockout way to do it.

Comment: A custom binding handler is defined here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702771/custom-knockout-binding-fires-twice-unexpectedly